# How to add the results of lapply or for loop to specific rows

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I have a database with 5 variables (columns). I want to subset the data frame, in order to check if a certain value of one specific column is present. If this is the case, then assign 1, else 0. Then paste the result (1 or 0) to a specific column of the restricted data frame, and then continue.

The data frame looks like the following:

```
 ## Year  Month Product  Supermarket  Price
 ## 2015    1      67         1          10
 ## 2015    1      65         1          11
 ## 2015    1      69         1          15
 ## 2015    2      65         2          20
 ## 2015    2      67         2          25
 ## 2015    2      67         3          15
 ## 2015    2      69         3          12
```

Now I want to restrict for each Year, Month and Supermarket and check if Product = 65 is present. If it is, then to assign 1 for the rows restricted in a new variable (column). If not, to assign 0.

I have tried using lapply:

```
prueba <- function(x)
ifelse(any(base$Product == 65),  1, 0)
lapply(unique(base$Supermarket) & unique(base$Year) & unique(base$Month), 
                  base$NewVar <- prueba)
```

but have the following result

```
Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'
```

Next, I try to make a for loop:

```
for(i in unique(base$Supermarket)) {
for(j in unique(base$Year))
for(h in unique(base$Month)) {
try <-  ifelse(any((filter(base, Supermarket == i, Year == j, Month == h))$Product == 65),  1, 0)

base[base$Supermarket == i && base$Year ==j && base$Month == h,]$NewVar <- try
}
}
}
```

And have the following results:

```
Error in if (nrow(try) == 0) { : argument has zero lenght
```

I shall say that the database has 50 million rows, so speed is an issue here (so I try to use lapply instead of for loop)
I do not how to obtain the proper result, which should be like the following:

```
 ## Year  Month Product  Supermarket  Price  NewVar
 ## 2015    1      67         1          10    1
 ## 2015    1      65         1          11    1
 ## 2015    1      69         1          15    1
 ## 2015    2      65         2          20    1
 ## 2015    2      67         2          25    1
 ## 2015    2      67         3          15    0
 ## 2015    2      69         3          12    0
```

Do not know how to solve the whole problem. When using lapply I get the "right" answer, but then could not paste the result to the right rows in the dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this easily in `base R`

```
df1$NewVar <- with(df1, ave(Product, Year, Month, Supermarket,
                                        FUN= function(x) 65 %in% x))
df1$NewVar
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. Just to know, why Product should be included? Also, what does with in this environment (look the help and say that it evaluate an R expression. Beautiful and simple.

Comment: @LeandroZipitria  After the first i.e. Product, all other variables are grouping variables, so the `x` refers to `Product`.  The `with` is used so that we don't have to use `df1$Product`, `df1$Year` etc, which can become a bit more wordy.

Answer (score 2):

For fast operation, try to use `data.table` or `dplyr`. With `data.table`, you can simply create the new variable with logic check grouped by the `Year, Month and Supermarket` variables(suppose your original data frame is called `df`):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, NewVar := as.numeric(65 %in% Product), .(Year, Month, Supermarket)]
df
#    Year Month Product Supermarket Price NewVar
# 1: 2015     1      67           1    10      1
# 2: 2015     1      65           1    11      1
# 3: 2015     1      69           1    15      1
# 4: 2015     2      65           2    20      1
# 5: 2015     2      67           2    25      1
# 6: 2015     2      67           3    15      0
# 7: 2015     2      69           3    12      0
```

Or correspondingly using `dplyr`: `df <- df %>% group_by(Year, Month, Supermarket) %>% mutate(NewVar = as.numeric(65 %in% Product))`

Comment: Product == 65? This doesn't seem right. The NewVar includes '1's for 67, 69 but not even all of those values.

Comment: @Mike OP is trying to label groups of `Year, Month and Supermarket` which contain product `65` instead of just those rows whose product is 65. This is essentially a summarizing of the original data but obviously OP would like to keep the shape of the data and add the label as a new column so that's how it goes like this.

Comment: Right but the desired output doesn't equate 1 with product 65. Look at your output too. Am I missing something?

Comment: Row 2 and Row 5 are the only two rows where `product == 65` and the New Var is equal to `1` at these two rows both in the desired output and my answer?

Comment: Thanks Mike for your answer. But the answer by @Psidom is perfect. I know that I get a "1" in rows that do not have Product ==65 in it. But this is exactly what I was looking for. I need to know if that supermarket in that day is selling the Product 65, but I will be working with Product 67 and 69 instead. So I need to construct a dummy variable. So the code need to put a "1" in every Product row for each supermarket/day if Product 65 is present, and 0 if not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
## read data
base <- c(2015, 1, 67, 1, 10,
          2015, 1, 65, 1, 11,
          2015, 1, 69, 1, 15,
          2015, 2, 65, 2, 20,
          2015, 2, 67, 2, 25,
          2015, 2, 67, 3, 15,
          2015, 2, 69, 3, 12)
base <- data.frame(matrix(base, 7, byrow = TRUE))
names(base) <- c('Year', 'Month', 'Product', 'Supermarket', 'Price')
```

Made a couple changes to function. I changed the object to match input (x) and specified the third element (since column of interest is column 3)

```
## create function
prueba <- function(x) ifelse(x[3] == 65, 1, 0)
```

To apply this function to each row, use the apply() function with 1 (for rows) `apply(x, 1, function)`.

```
base$new_var <- apply(base, 1, prueba)
base
##   Year Month Product Supermarket Price new_var
## 1 2015     1      67           1    10       0
## 2 2015     1      65           1    11       1
## 3 2015     1      69           1    15       0
## 4 2015     2      65           2    20       1
## 5 2015     2      67           2    25       0
## 6 2015     2      67           3    15       0
## 7 2015     2      69           3    12       0
```

You could also create a new variable and conditionally enter '1' to relevant rows. This is the way I'd do it:

```
base$new_var <- 0
base$new_var[base$Product == 65] <- 1
base
##   Year Month Product Supermarket Price new_var
## 1 2015     1      67           1    10       0
## 2 2015     1      65           1    11       1
## 3 2015     1      69           1    15       0
## 4 2015     2      65           2    20       1
## 5 2015     2      67           2    25       0
## 6 2015     2      67           3    15       0
## 7 2015     2      69           3    12       0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and the new code. Not exactly what I was looking for (see the previous post), but also useful. Best